# Ошибка `user-defined type not defined`. VBA для OneNote

Tags: excel, vba, visual-basic

**Используется**:

- Windows 7
- Excel-2016
- OneNote-2016

Пробую выполнить пример согласно этой статьи: [Navigating to a Notebook in OneNote 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh377178(v=office.14).aspx).

При запуске кода (F5) в строке:

```
Private Function GetFirstOneNoteNotebookNodes(oneNote As OneNote16.Application) As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
```

выпадает ошибка:

```
user-defined type not defined
```

**Вопрос:** как исправить?

Настройки 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: уверены, что подключены все необходимые библиотеки?

Comment: @Anatol Дополнил скрины

Comment: Ну для начала неплохо бы определиться, какой из этих двух типов не нравится компилятору. Поэкспериментируйте, объявите выше переменные одного и второго типа по очереди и посмотрите, на кого ругнётся

Comment: @Anatol Не могли бы вы внести ваше предложение в код, а то я плохо разбираюсь в VBA. Код находится по ссылке [ссылка на КОД](https://codeshare.io/5QmYNw)